# Best PHP Image Crop Class

Tags: php, image, class, image-processing

I'm designing a website and I need to:

- Upload the image
- Validate that it's an image (and not, oh I don't know.... a virus :) )
- Resize the Image
- convert to jpg

*Essentially basic image upload*

Instead of writing my own I'm trying to find a PHP class that let's me do all this, because as Jeff Atwood said, ["never design what you can steal"](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2004/12/never-design-what-you-can-steal.html)

So far, Ive found:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997127/php-class-to-upload-image-from-url-and-resize-it (I know it looks like a duplicate, but its not because it is asking for a URL fetcher)
- http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/image-resizing-made-easy-with-php/
- http://www.verot.net/php_class_upload.htm
- http://blog.freelancer-id.com/index.php/2010/03/21/php-image-crop-resize-upload
- http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2181-PHP-Process-files-and-images-uploaded-via-a-form.html
- https://github.com/dimo414/imgupload

Does anyone have any experience with these classes? Can you recommend an outstanding image upload class?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I tend to use a framework of one description or another, which cover's the file upload part. However, do have a recommendation for the cropping bit:

Imagine - https://github.com/avalanche123/Imagine

And if you want to make the uploader a tiny bit better than just an input type=file, try:

https://github.com/valums/file-uploader

Answer (score 17):

My personal favorite Image Manipulation Library is [`WideImage`](http://wideimage.sourceforge.net/). It makes is ridiculously easy to do that kind of task.

```
WideImage::load('pic.png')
->crop('center', 'center', 90, 50)->saveToFile('cropped/pic.jpg');
```

As for validating if it is actually an image or not, use [`finfo`](http://php.net/fileinfo) or [`PEAR::Mime_type`](http://pear.php.net/package/MIME_Type). I personally prefer [`PEAR::Mime_Type`](http://pear.php.net/package/MIME_Type). It uses `finfo` but it's just simpler to use.

*Using `finfo`:*

```
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$mimetype = finfo_file($finfo, $filename);

$isImage = (preg_match('#^image/#', $mimetype) === 1);
```

*Using `PEAR::Mime_Type`:*

```
$mimetype = MIME_Type::autoDetect($filename);

$isImage = MIME_Type::wildcardMatch('image/*', $mimetype);
```

Comment: this is a great answer. I really love your solution since it's simple and very nice to use ;)

Answer (score 5):

**Check out JCROP Plugin**

*This will be uselful for all*

[JCROP Image cropping----deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html](http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html)

[image]

Comment: +1 For a really great and sleek plugin, and for those of you guyz who are wondering about implementing this with php, there is already an implementation inside the `examples` given inside the download package....

Comment: Easy to understand and install. I have Implemented this in 2 or more web applications..

Answer (score 4):

The class upload from Colin Verot http://www.verot.net/php_class_upload.htm is my favourite. I use in in all my projects. Like the way you 'talk' to the class and only use what your need, but gives plenty of configuration/methods to tweak it to your exact needs. Great class!

Answer (score 4):

there's also this [lightweight image manipulation library written in PHP](http://stefangabos.ro/php-libraries/zebra-image/) called **Zebra_Image** that's very small, not bloated with zillion of functions you'll never use, highly optimized, with a [great documentation](http://stefangabos.ro/wp-content/docs/Zebra_Image/Zebra_Image/Zebra_Image.html) and which is actively maintained.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend to use Smart Image Resizer
http://shiftingpixel.com/2008/03/03/smart-image-resizer/

**You get the best image quality after resizing**

It's extremely simple to use. It uses image cache.

Comment: Just an FYI, this will require a version of GD that supports imageconvolution().

Answer (score 2):

I recommend [SimpleImage](https://github.com/claviska/SimpleImage), it is very simple, has only one file and is updated.

Example of use:

```
$img = new SimpleImage('image.jpg');

// Resize the image to 320x200
$img->resize(320, 200);

$img->save('new-image.jpg');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to migrate into an MVC PHP framework, I strongly recommend [Codeigniter](http://codeigniter.com/).

Besides several other classes and libraries that handle pagination, tables, security, forms, etc CI also has nice upload and image manipulation classes that are very handy and flexible. 
I believe they can do all you require (just not sure about jpg conversion).

You can check them out at:

[Image manipulation class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/image_lib.html)

[File uploading class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html)

Answer (score 0):

I am using this Image crop, it working well

[Simple PHP Image cCrop](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nJTiLGrrnzA&feature=youtu.be)