# How to show image always in a square

Tags: php, html, css, image

I want to show image inside the square of fixed dimension of 400 * 400. Hence to maintain the aspect ratio, it is possible that if width is more, then width would be reduced and remaining space as per the aspect ratio would be filled with some background color (I can give color on div). Similarly if the height is more, the height would be adjusted to show it as per aspect ratio and then remaining space would be filled with background.

Could anybody help me how to achieve this? Can this be done with imagemagick?
http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried searching for image cropping/resizing tutorials/code/blogs/documentation?

Comment: Yes but couldn't find which one would help me.

Comment: It's  just a question of simple math, if you are not familiar with doing math as you code i suggest you look for an image manipulation library or crop library that could solve your problem.

Comment: If the width is wider than height, give a width of 100% if vice versa give height of 100% and overflow hidden

Comment: here's someone who had the same problem but googled a bit first: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6460578/best-php-image-crop-class

Comment: @jtavares: Did you read my comments? I too googled. How did you assume I didn't google - **"but googled a bit first"** ?

Comment: because i found that link on the first result from the search "php crop library"

Comment: but I didn't search that term and hence it didn't appear on my result as first result.

Answer (score 0):

Use phpthumb.

```
    require_once '/path/to/ThumbLib.inc.php';  
    $thumb = PhpThumbFactory::create('path/to/image.jpg');  

    //$thumb->resize(400, 400);  
    // resize image and make thumbnail by cropping image automatically
    $thumb->adaptiveResize(400, 400)->save('/path/to/thumb.jpg'); ;
```

for more reading goto [PHPTHUMB](https://github.com/masterexploder/PHPThumb/wiki/Basic-Usage)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding width and height

That again you can do this at css :D

Answer (score 0):

If displaying the image with the right size is good enough you don't need to create a scaled version, just scale it in a web page using CSS:

```
div {
  width:400px;
  height:400px;
  background:url('https://placekitten.com/400/600');
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size:contain;
  background-position:50% 50%
}
```

Vary the size of the placekitten image to see the way images are scaled.

Play with an example on jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lontevb3/1/

Answer (score -4):

You

- Calculate the aspect ratio of the image
- Check if one of the image dimensions is longer than your 'frame'
- If both are longer, then you pick the largest dimension of the two
- Scale the picture so that the longest dimension is the same as that of your frame (400px)
- Scale the other dimension so that it is 400*aspect ratio px

Answer (score -5):

How about create a `<div>` and set the background image?

Comment: Hey there. You should explain how this would solve the problem?

Comment: @Jubobs:  It's an attempt at an answer.  It may not be a good answer, but it's an attempt at one.

Comment: @Makoto It's merely a suggestion. An honest attempt at an answer would at least involved a toy example demonstrating the idea. Not good enough.