# Send multiple cropped images in cropper.js using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, cropperjs

I found this pen https://codepen.io/dimmby/details/PvWbQX that I needed to use in my project. The code is exactly what I required so I integrated it into my website. The problem is, I can't figure out how to upload the cropped images to the server. Here is my code:

```js
var c;
var galleryImagesContainer = document.getElementById('galleryImages');
var imageCropFileInput = document.getElementById('imageCropFileInput');
var cropperImageInitCanvas = document.getElementById('cropperImg');
var cropImageButton = document.getElementById('cropImageBtn');
// Crop Function On change
function imagesPreview(input) {
  var cropper;
  galleryImagesContainer.innerHTML = '';
  var img = [];
  if (cropperImageInitCanvas.cropper) {
    cropperImageInitCanvas.cropper.destroy();
    cropImageButton.style.display = 'none';
    cropperImageInitCanvas.width = 0;
    cropperImageInitCanvas.height = 0;
  }
  if (input.files.length) {
    var i = 0;
    var index = 0;
    for (let singleFile of input.files) {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function(event) {
        var blobUrl = event.target.result;
        img.push(new Image());
        img[i].onload = function(e) {
          // Canvas Container
          var singleCanvasImageContainer = document.createElement('div');
          singleCanvasImageContainer.id = 'singleImageCanvasContainer' + index;
          singleCanvasImageContainer.className = 'singleImageCanvasContainer';
          // Canvas Close Btn
          var singleCanvasImageCloseBtn = document.createElement('button');
          var singleCanvasImageCloseBtnText = document.createTextNode('Close');
          // var singleCanvasImageCloseBtnText = document.createElement('i');
          // singleCanvasImageCloseBtnText.className = 'fa fa-times';
          singleCanvasImageCloseBtn.id = 'singleImageCanvasCloseBtn' + index;
          singleCanvasImageCloseBtn.className = 'singleImageCanvasCloseBtn';
          singleCanvasImageCloseBtn.onclick = function() {
            removeSingleCanvas(this)
          };
          singleCanvasImageCloseBtn.appendChild(singleCanvasImageCloseBtnText);
          singleCanvasImageContainer.appendChild(singleCanvasImageCloseBtn);
          // Image Canvas
          var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
          canvas.id = 'imageCanvas' + index;
          canvas.className = 'imageCanvas singleImageCanvas';
          canvas.width = e.currentTarget.width;
          canvas.height = e.currentTarget.height;
          canvas.onclick = function() {
            cropInit(canvas.id);
          };
          singleCanvasImageContainer.appendChild(canvas)
          // Canvas Context
          var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
          ctx.drawImage(e.currentTarget, 0, 0);
          // galleryImagesContainer.append(canvas);
          galleryImagesContainer.appendChild(singleCanvasImageContainer);
          while (document.querySelectorAll('.singleImageCanvas').length == input.files.length) {
            var allCanvasImages = document.querySelectorAll('.singleImageCanvas')[0].getAttribute('id');
            cropInit(allCanvasImages);
            break;
          };
          urlConversion();
          index++;
        };
        img[i].src = blobUrl;
        i++;
      }
      reader.readAsDataURL(singleFile);
    }
  }
}
imageCropFileInput.addEventListener("change", function(event) {
  imagesPreview(event.target);
});
// Initialize Cropper
function cropInit(selector) {
  c = document.getElementById(selector);
  console.log(document.getElementById(selector));
  if (cropperImageInitCanvas.cropper) {
    cropperImageInitCanvas.cropper.destroy();
  }
  var allCloseButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.singleImageCanvasCloseBtn');
  for (let element of allCloseButtons) {
    element.style.display = 'block';
  }
  c.previousSibling.style.display = 'none';
  // c.id = croppedImg;
  var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
  var imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
  var image = cropperImageInitCanvas;
  image.width = c.width;
  image.height = c.height;
  var ctx = image.getContext('2d');
  ctx.putImageData(imgData, 0, 0);
  cropper = new Cropper(image, {
    aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
    preview: '.img-preview',
    crop: function(event) {
      cropImageButton.style.display = 'block';
    }
  });
}
// Crop Image
function image_crop() {
  if (cropperImageInitCanvas.cropper) {
    var cropcanvas = cropperImageInitCanvas.cropper.getCroppedCanvas({
      width: 250,
      height: 250
    });
    // document.getElementById('cropImages').appendChild(cropcanvas);
    var ctx = cropcanvas.getContext('2d');
    var imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, cropcanvas.width, cropcanvas.height);
    // var image = document.getElementById(c);
    c.width = cropcanvas.width;
    c.height = cropcanvas.height;
    var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
    ctx.putImageData(imgData, 0, 0);
    cropperImageInitCanvas.cropper.destroy();
    cropperImageInitCanvas.width = 0;
    cropperImageInitCanvas.height = 0;
    cropImageButton.style.display = 'none';
    var allCloseButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.singleImageCanvasCloseBtn');
    for (let element of allCloseButtons) {
      element.style.display = 'block';
    }
    urlConversion();
  } else {
    alert('Please select any Image you want to crop');
  }
}
cropImageButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  image_crop();
});
// Image Close/Remove
function removeSingleCanvas(selector) {
  selector.parentNode.remove();
  urlConversion();
}
// Get Converted Url
function urlConversion() {
  var allImageCanvas = document.querySelectorAll('.singleImageCanvas');
  var convertedUrl = '';
  for (let element of allImageCanvas) {
    convertedUrl += element.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
    convertedUrl += 'img_url';
  }
  document.getElementById('profile_img_data').value = convertedUrl;
}
```

```css
.myform {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 50px 100px;
}

.imageset {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#galleryImages,
#cropper {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}

canvas {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

#cropper {}

#cropperImg {
  /*max-width: 0; max-height: 0;*/
  max-height: 300px;
}

#cropImageBtn {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 30px 0px;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  background: #EEC900;
  border: none;
}

.myform img {
  width: 100%;
}

.img-preview {
  float: left;
}

.singleImageCanvasContainer {
  max-width: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 2px;
}

.singleImageCanvasCloseBtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cropperjs/1.4.0/cropper.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cropperjs/1.4.0/cropper.js"></script>

<div class="myform">
  <?php include('server/errors.php');?>
  <form action="upload-vehicle.php" method="Post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="imageset">
      <input type="file" id="imageCropFileInput" name="image[]" multiple accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.png">
      <input type="hidden" id="profile_img_data" name="profile_img_data">
      <div class="img-preview"></div>
      <div id="galleryImages"></div>
      <div id="cropper">
        <canvas id="cropperImg" width="0" height="0"></canvas>
        <button class="cropImageBtn" id="cropImageBtn" onclick="return false;">Crop</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="buttongroup"><button name="uploadvehicle">Upload Vehicle</button></div>
  </form>
</div>
```

I have tried using the jquery code provided in the cropper.js description but I was unsuccessful.

Comment: Where are you getting stuck? You might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38752414/924299) helpful, specifically code for "send image to the server". However, "[f]or better image quality, you can upload the original image and the cropped data to a server and do the crop work on the server," [getCroppedCanvas()](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropperjs#getcroppedcanvasoptions).

Comment: Has anything changed since [this similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66064955/post-multiple-cropped-images-by-cropper-js-to-server-with-php)?

Comment: @showdev  the answer deals with single images not multiple images and the solutions do not work for me. And about cropping image on the server...how do I do that.

Comment: The logic of uploading cropped images to the server seems the same regardless of the number of images. For multiple images, execute the same code for each image. To crop on the server, submit the file and appropriate crop coordinates with your form and then use PHP to crop the image, using either an [existing library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6460578/) or your own [custom functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1855996/). For what it's worth, I like [Colin Verot's class.upload.php](https://github.com/verot/class.upload.php).